# Node.js with MySQL-returning a string

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am learning JS right now, trying to write a simple server for game in NodeJS. I wanted to get two values from database ( a Varchar, an Int), and get them as a single string.

```
function top5FromDatabase(callback){
    var curSTR='';
    var out1='ba';
    var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM highscore ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5';
    connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        for (var i=0, j=1;i<rows.length;i++, j++) {
            curSTR+=j.toString();
            curSTR+=' ';
            curSTR+=rows[i].name;
            curSTR+=' ';
            curSTR+=rows[i].score; 
            curSTR+=' ';

            curSTR=curSTR.toString();
        }
        console.log('Here is:' + curSTR);
        out1=curSTR;

    });
    callback(out1+ ' e o l');
}
```

I tried to get what is wrong multiple times: the console log always outputs the line I want to get, so I tried checking everything (that's why there are so many separate lines for curSTR).
The callback is getting "undefined" as out1.

I deduced that something is wrong with rows[i].name and rows[i].score - tried to get those wihh rows[i].xxx.toString(), but it also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `callback(out1+ ' e o l');` inside the `.query` callback.

In your code, `callback` is called before the `connection.query` executes.